# Every year in september, my Date list skips a month and I cannot reproduce it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, gantt-chart

#### The problem

I am building an Open-Source Vue Application. It has a Gantt-Chart to show tasks as a timeline. It has an option for users to set a date range, by default it shows the current and next month.

Every year in september, this chart breaks. Instead of showing all months, it skips the next month:

[image]

This is what it should look like instead:
[image]

There's been an ongoing issue about this [here](https://kolaente.dev/vikunja/frontend/issues/69).

#### The catch

I can't reproduce this. Even when I use Browserstack to be able to use the exact same browser/OS combination my users are using. It works fine for me on every device and browser I tried it so far. Because I cannot reproduce it, I can't really debug it, let alone fix it.

This also hints it only affects some users and not that many.

#### The code

This is the code building the years/months/days data structure:

```js
// Layout: years => [months => [days]]
let years = {}
for (
    let d = this.startDate;
    d <= this.endDate;
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
) {
    let date = new Date(d)
    if (years[date.getFullYear() + ''] === undefined) {
        years[date.getFullYear() + ''] = {}
    }
    if (
        years[date.getFullYear() + ''][date.getMonth() + ''] ===
        undefined
    ) {
        years[date.getFullYear() + ''][date.getMonth() + ''] = []
    }
    years[date.getFullYear() + ''][date.getMonth() + ''].push(date)
    this.fullWidth += this.dayWidth
}
this.$set(this, 'days', years) // I know, that variable name doesn't make any sense
```

Which I am then showing the user like this:

```
<template v-for="(y, yk) in days">
    <div :key="yk + 'year'" class="months">
        <div
            :key="mk + 'month'"
            class="month"
            v-for="(m, mk) in days[yk]"
        >
            {{
                new Date(
                    new Date(yk).setMonth(mk),
                ).toLocaleString('en-us', {month: 'long'})
            }},
            {{ new Date(yk).getFullYear() }}
            <div class="days">
                <div
                    :class="{ today: d.toDateString() === now.toDateString() }"
                    :key="dk + 'day'"
                    :style="{ width: dayWidth + 'px' }"
                    class="day"
                    v-for="(d, dk) in days[yk][mk]"
                >
                    <span class="theday" v-if="dayWidth > 25">
                        {{ d.getDate() }}
                    </span>
                    <span class="weekday" v-if="dayWidth > 25">
                        {{ d.toLocaleString('en-us', {weekday: 'short'}) }} 
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The full code of the component is [here](https://kolaente.dev/vikunja/frontend/src/branch/main/src/components/tasks/gantt-component.vue).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with

```
new Date(new Date(yk).setMonth(mk))
```

You expect for instance for `new Date(new Date(2021, 11, 31).setMonth(8))` it will be the end of September 2021? Nope. It will be 1th of October because September does not have 31 days and only 30.

The date `yk` should be the first day of each month to modify a month correctly.